Recursive identification and matrix inversion
I have observed that whenever I read classic books on recursive system identification, it is normally advised to avoid matrix inversion. However, I'm not totally sure if matrix inversion inside a recursive algorithm remains a problem nowadays, as small matrix (with n < 10 for a squared matrix) can be inverted pretty efficiently and fast with nowadays computers. I have also made the test of applying matrix inversions and the algorithms seem to work fine. My question is if this matrix inversion avoidance is due to mathematical reasons, or mostly due to the complexity it demanded from computers decades ago (as the great classics can be from the 70s and 80s).

I think that thers is also a numerical stability issue
